# When to monitor UxSTAbits.TRMT and UxSTAbits.UTXBF

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, register

According to the reference manual on UART for PIC [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000582e.pdf)(page 7), the UxSTA register have two read-only bits; TRMT and UTXBF. While writing a simple transmission program over UART, I didn't notice any change if I include

```
while(UxSTAbits.TMRT != 1);
```

or

```
while(UxSTAbits.UTXBF);
```

before I send anything with the UxTXREG buffer. In what case is each of these bit relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In block diagram at page 15, it is shown that the Transmit FIFO buffer is followed by Transmit Shift Register.

[image]

`UxSTAbits.UTXBF` bit indicates if the FIFO is full. If the FIFO is not full, you can write to `UxTXREG` register.

`UxSTAbits.TMRT` indicates if the last transmission has completed (FIFO and shift register are both empty). You should not turn off the UART or put MCU into sleep while the transmission is not completed. If you are not planning to do those, you can safely ignore the state of this bit.

Comment: @Asher Farooqui, The answer from user930473 is generally correct. There are some specific cases where an implementation can become problematic. For these cases you need to consult the errata for the specific device you are coding for. For example some parts when the application polls the UART status register rapidly it can provoke silicon bugs.